# Karate exception 'com.intuit.karate.exception.KarateException

Tags: rest, api, exception, automated-tests, karate

I got the below setup.Its in the following repository.
https://github.com/Yogeshwari21/karatecheck/tree/master/src/test/java/FeatureTest1

I have not shared the actual variables used, i have created a sample set up in the above repository.

I am trying to create multiple data for a request and whenever i trigger the test, i get below exception

> KarateException: AlertParadef.feature:4 -
>   org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;
>   lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 9; XML document structures must start and
>   end within the same entity. at ✽.Given def param1=

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `<field4>` is missing in the CSV, it became invalid XML in the feature file.

Also please read this section carefully: https://github.com/intuit/karate#scenario-outline-enhancements

Comment: Thanks, i was able to update a request its working. Although  when i create a file with an array of fields then it doesn't like it my data input looks as follows ["field_name1","data","field_data2"] when i give this i get the following exception  
com.intuit.karate.exception.KarateException: exportTest.feature:13 - net.minidev.json.parser.ParseException: Unexpected End Of File position 43: EOF